# How to ban Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, conditional-comments

I try to ban the Internet Explorer by a meta tag in my template.

`template.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<f:view locale="de_DE">
<h:head>
    <f:facet name="first">
        <h:outputText
            value="&lt;!--[if IE]&gt;
        &lt;h1&gt;No IE support.&lt;/h1&gt;
        &lt;![endif]--&gt;"
            escape="false" />
    </f:facet>
...
```

In that way it doesn't work. How can I achieve it?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what happens when you try to open this page in IE8?

Comment: The jsf rendered page shows up. Instead I only want to have the text "No IE support".

Comment: Does the generated HTML contain your conditional comment?

Comment: Yes. And if I'm pressing like wild the reload button in IE the message shows up for a short time before it get overlayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've there is not a meta tag, but just an IE conditional comment which conditionally shows a piece of HTML code depending on whether the enduser is using IE or not. To present a piece of HTML code in the page body, you have to put the HTML code in the `<body>`, not in the `<head>`.

```
<h:body>
    ...
    <h:outputText
        value="&lt;!--[if IE]&gt;
    &lt;h1&gt;No IE support.&lt;/h1&gt;
    &lt;![endif]--&gt;"
        escape="false" />
    ...
</h:body>
```

Note that this doesn't magically hide the remainder of the page in any way. You'd have to expand this by including a CSS `<link>` which contains something like `#content { display: none; }`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, as you're based on your question history already using OmniFaces, you may find the [`<o:conditionalComment>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/conditionalComment) helpful to render IE conditional comments in a developer friendly way in JSF.

```
<h:body>
    ...
    <o:conditionalComment if="IE">
        <h1>No IE support.</h1>
    </o:conditionalComment>
    ...
</h:body>
```